Joomla 2.5 with Virtuemart captcha problems
I took over a Joomla 2.5 website. It is currently running Virtuemart 2.0.10 on PHP 5.5.18 - very old stuff. I know I should upgrade it, but for now my time is limited for it - so I looking for quick fix to my issue.
Recaptcha V1, which the site supported is removed by Google since 2018. I got the plugin from here - https://www.tabulizer.com/index.php/support/knowledge-base/view-article/161-how-to-enable-recaptcha-v2-in-joomla-2-5 and it appears to only work properly but only when I disable (by renaming mootools-core.js and mootools-more.js in /media/system/js). With them enabled, either the captcha doesn't show (Firefox on any platform) or keeps spinning (Chrome on Mac). Strangely it works on Windows Chrome and Android Chrome.
However, this breaks navigation in Admin Panel of Joomla and I was reading that it would cause issues with modals(not sure where used though) and also it's needed for VirtueMart.
I tried to upgrade mootools to 1.6.0 from their official site (non-compat files) with no luck.
Any idea how to resolve the issue properly?

In terms of a quick fix, the only option I can see is to find an alternative CAPTCHA extension for Joomla 2.5.
Unfortunately, most developers have deleted Joomla 2.5 downloads from their websites since Joomla 2.5 has been officially unsupported since December 2014.
Note: Beware of extensions available from websites other than the official developer websites as non-official versions of extensions could contain malware.
You could try "OSOL Captcha" which still has a Joomla 2.5 version available on the developer website.
Try searching the Joomla Extension Directory for currently listed CAPTCHA extensions with older "Date Added" dates and check the developer websites to see if they have an older version for Joomla 2.5. If it looks like a Joomla 2.5 version was available previously, you could also politely ask the developer if they still have a copy and could they supply it?
For example, "EasyCalcCheck Plus" and "EasyCalcCheck Captcha" are popular anti-spam extensions which had Joomla 2.5 versions previously. The developer no longer offers these for download via his website but may be open to receiving a polite request.
Searching Github for Joomla 2.5 + recaptcha shows https://github.com/milkycode/joomla_recaptcha_j25 which may help but I haven't used it and can't say for sure.
There are only so many quick fixes that can be done and the website will need to be upgraded at some stage to keep it going.
